# How, if possible, can an .sql file be executed against an oracle database from a bash script

Tags: oracle, scripting, command-line

Is it possible to execute an sql file (a text file containing several SQL statements) against an oracle database from a bash shell command line (e.g. no graphical GUI and no interactive clients)

Something like:
sqlplus -f queries.sql ...

The command is expected to execute all the statements in the queries.sql file and exit with an appropriate exit code (e.g. 0 if all queries executed correctly, nonzero otherwise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus user/pass@server/DATABASE<<THEEND

-- Change "1" to the desired fatal return code

whenever sqlerror exit 1;

@yoursqlscript.sql

quit;

THEEND
```

Or you can just run:

```
sqlplus user/pass@server/DATABASE @yoursqlscript
```

... and put the `whenever sqlerror exit 1;` at the top of your .sql script(s).

Comment: +1, you should also use the `-L` option so that sqlplus will return immediately with an error if it fails to login.

Comment: The Or part of your answer, with
sqlplus user/pass@server/DATABASE @yoursqlscript
works putting the statement (with an ending ";") at the beginning of the script